# Going from Fourier sum to Fourier integral - confusion on intermediate step

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

How does it solve the $A_0$ term?
Can one prove this with an example? I don't know how to prove it to myself with an example

In my lecture notes, my lecturer is trying to justify $C_n$ as weighting the sine and cosine terms in the Fourier integral differently despite how it looks explicitly in the Fourier infinite sum, that is, in:

[image]
[image]

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} C_n \ e^{ik_nx} \ $$

I have two main confusions with this:

1) How does this rewriting with $a_n$ and $b_n$ resolve the $A_0$ term?

2) I don't see how the substitution of $A_n$ and $B_n$ for $a_n$ and $b_n$ is valid, even given the changed summation ranges. I also don't know how I'd prove it with an example. How can one do this?

Comment: I am not sure what your difficulty is.  The only note is that for each $n \ne 0$, there are two terms involved $n$ and $-n$, while there is only one term for $n=0$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg basically, I don’t see how this preserves equality. And I’m not sure how to figure out how

Comment: You did not show how $A_n$ and $B_n$ derive from $C_n$.  From the setup it looks like $A_n=C_n+C_{-n}$, forcing $\frac{A_0}{2}$ to be the constant term.  If the objective is to get the expansions in terms of $a_n$ and $b_n$, why do you have the intermediate step with $A_n$ and $B_n$?  $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}C_ne^{ik_nx}=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}C_n(cos(k_nx)+isin(k_nx))$.  Therefore $a_n=C_n$ and $b_n=iC_n$

Comment: If you are trying to get $A_n$ and $B_n$ as the final result, then the point about $A_0=C_n+C_{-n}$ when $n=0$ forcing the division by $2$ holds.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I've attached the full section of the lecture notes for clarity. I'm not trying to point at how to $A_n$ and $B_n$ as the final result. I'm trying to understand why the substitution my lecturer made from $A_n$ and $B_n$ to $a_n$ to $b_n$ works. Sorry if this was unclear! Also, I'm not sure if what you wrote agrees with my lecturer?

Comment: The lecture notes are correct and my comments agree with them.  Try looking at what is going on for a specific $n\ne 0$ using $k_{-n}=-k_n$ and the Euler identity.  I think the lecture would have been clearer if it went from $C_n$ to $a_n$ and $b_n$ first and then to $A_n$ and $B_n$.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify I'll derive the $f(x)$ expression directly.  $C_ne^{ik_nx}=C_n(cos(k_nx)+isin(k_nx))$.  Therefore $a_n=C_n$ and $b_n=iC_n$, for all n.
For $n \gt 0$ use the fact that $k_{-n}=-k_n$ and cos is even while sin is odd.  Therefore for $n \gt 0, A_n=a_n+a_{-n}$ while $B_n=b_n-b_{-n}$.
$A_0$ has to be treated as a special case.  $k_0=-k_{-0}$ forces $k_0=0$, so there is no sin term and the cos term $=1$, while $A_0=a_0+a_{-0}$ means $a_0$ is counted twice, so that $\frac{A_0}{2}$ is what is needed for the final form $f(x)=\frac{A_0}{2}+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}A_ncos(k_nx)+B_nsin(k_nx)$.

I can see that the lecture notes are somewhat confusing, since they work backwards from $A_n$ and $B_n$ rather than forward.

Answer (score 0):

The "trick" is in the sum from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ where $|n|$ is counted once for $|n|=0$ , and twice for $|n| \ge 1$.